# Javascript and onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

I have created a script, which holds a div-container. The moment i move the mouse quickly left and right on the container, it does not work anymore. Google Chrome does not process it properly either, why?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>move container</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var position=0;
var interval;
var isRunning = false;

function moveRight0()
{
if (position => 20){

position = 19;

} 

if (isRunning==true){
isRunning = false;
return; 

} 

if (isRunning==false) { 

isRunning = true
document.getElementById("container0").style.left = position+"px";
position++;

if(position==20)
{ 
clearInterval(interval);
interval=0; 
}

}

}

function moveLeft0()
{
if (position < 1){

position = 0;

}


if (isRunning==true){
isRunning = false;
return; 
} 


if (isRunning==false) { 

isRunning = true
document.getElementById("container0").style.left = position+"px";
position--;
if(position<1)
{

clearInterval(interval);
interval = 0;
}

} 

}

function al(){
alert(interval);
}

function setIntervalLeft0()
{ 
interval = setInterval(moveLeft0,10);
}

function setIntervalRight0()
{ 
interval = setInterval(moveRight0,10);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onmouseover="setIntervalRight0()" onmouseout="setIntervalLeft0()" id="container0" style="width:50px; height:20px; position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0px; left:0px">text</div><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="al()" name="zeige">
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Im dont really understand what your code is supposed to do, but i made a few minor changes and it works on chrome.

Note: you have an error in your code

```
if (position => 20){
//=> is invalid, use >= instead
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2r9usf4h/